# EclipseLink Error 168 and 28019 ruined my CRUD JPA system

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, crud

So i'm making a very simple crud system and all was working well until i finished up the crud functionality and everything took a turn for the worse, the program no longer started and i am instead given a screen or error messages repeating eclipselink errors 168 and 28019 over and over, heres my whole program

Cashier Class

```
package SDev3Repeat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CASHIER")
@SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
public class Cashier {

@Id
private int cashierId;
private String name;
private String address;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar DOB;                             //Date of Birth of the cashier

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "transID")
private Bill bill;

public Cashier(){

}

public Cashier(int cashierId, String name, String address, Calendar DOB) {
    this.cashierId = cashierId;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public int getCashierId() {
    return cashierId;
}

public void setCashierId(int cashierId) {
    this.cashierId = cashierId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public Calendar getDOB() {
    return DOB;
}

public void setDOB(Calendar DOB) {
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public Bill getTransaction() {
    return bill;
}

public void setTransaction(Bill bill) {
    this.bill = bill;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String d = String.format("%1$s %2$tB %2$td, %2$tY", 
                     " Date of Birth:", DOB);
    return "Cashier ID: "+cashierId+" |    Cashier Name: "+name+" |    Cashier Address: "+address+" |    Cashier Date Of Birth: "+d;
}
}
```

Coffee Class

```
package SDev3Repeat;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "COFFEE")
@SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
public class Coffee {

@Id
private int coffeeId;
private String type;
private String size;
private double price;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSID")
private Bill trans;

public Coffee(){

}

public Coffee(int coffeeId, String type, String size, double price){
    this.coffeeId = coffeeId;
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
}

public int getCoffeeId() {
    return coffeeId;
}

public void setCoffeeId(int coffeeId) {
    this.coffeeId = coffeeId;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public void setTrans(Bill trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return " ID of Coffee: "+coffeeId+" |    Type of Coffee: " + type + " |    Size of Coffee: " + size + " |    Price of Coffee: " + price;
}


}
```

Bill class
    package SDev3Repeat;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BILL")
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
@SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
public class Bill {

@Id
private int transId;
private double bill;
private final double VAT = .09;             //VAT for hot food and drinks is 9%


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "trans", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Coffee> clist = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(mappedBy="bill")
private Cashier cashier;

private String tempname = cashier.getName();

public Bill() {
}

public Bill(int transId, double bill,String name) {
    this.transId = transId;
    this.bill = bill;
    this.tempname = name;
}

public int getTransId() {
    return transId;
}

public void setTransId(int transId) {
    this.transId = transId;
}

public double getBill() {
    return bill;
}

public void setBill(double bill) {
    this.bill = bill;
}

public String getTempname() {
    return tempname;
}

public void setTempname(String tempname) {
    this.tempname = tempname;
}

public List<Coffee> getClist() {
    return clist;
}

public void setClist(List<Coffee> clist) {
    this.clist = clist;
}

public Cashier getCashier() {
    return cashier;
}

public void setCashier(Cashier cashier) {
    this.cashier = cashier;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s="";
    for(int i=0;i<clist.size();i++) {
        s+= clist.get(i);
    }
    return s;
}  

public double calcBill(Double tempBill){
    bill = tempBill + (tempBill * VAT);
    return bill;
}

}
```

TestCoffee MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.*;

public class TestCoffee {
public static void main(String[] args){

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SDEVRepeatCAPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    dob.set(1992, 06, 23);        
    Cashier cashier = new Cashier(1,"John Smith", "123 South Street, Dublin",dob);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(cashier);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Coffee c = new Coffee(1,"Espresso","Solo",2.00);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(2);
    c.setType("Espresso");
    c.setSize("Doppio");
    c.setPrice(2.35);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(3);
    c.setType("Americano");
    c.setSize("Large");
    c.setPrice(2.85);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(4);
    c.setType("Americano");
    c.setSize("Medium");
    c.setPrice(2.50);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(5);
    c.setType("Cappuccino");
    c.setSize("Large");
    c.setPrice(3.45);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(6);
    c.setType("Cappuccino");
    c.setSize("Medium");
    c.setPrice(3.00);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(7);
    c.setType("Flat white");
    c.setSize("Small");
    c.setPrice(3.25);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(8);
    c.setType("Caffè Latte");
    c.setSize("Large");
    c.setPrice(3.45);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(9);
    c.setType("Caffè Latte");
    c.setSize("Medium");
    c.setPrice(3.00);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(10);
    c.setType("Caffè Mocha");
    c.setSize("Large");
    c.setPrice(4.00);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    c.setCoffeeId(11);
    c.setType("Caffè Mocha");
    c.setSize("Medium");
    c.setPrice(3.50);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();


    Bill b = new Bill(1,10.20,"John Smith");

    System.out.println("Would you like to Create(Enter C),Read(Enter R),Update(Enter U) or Delete(Enter D):");
    String choice = in.nextLine(); 
    int IdChoice;
    int transId = 1;
    int coffId = 11;
    int cashId = 1;
    String cont = "y";
while("y".equalsIgnoreCase(cont)){    
    if("C".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                                       //finished
        System.out.println("From what class would you like to Create? Transaction(Enter T), Cashier(enter Cash) or Coffee(Enter Coff):");
        choice = in.nextLine();
        if("T".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                                   //finished
            System.out.println("Please enter Total for bill - vat:");
            double tempbill = in.nextDouble();
            b.setBill(b.calcBill(tempbill));
            transId++;
            b.setTransId(transId);
            System.out.println("Please enter Cashiers ID:");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            cashier = em.find(Cashier.class, IdChoice);
            b.setTempname(cashier.getName());
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(b);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else if("Cash".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                          //finished
            System.out.println("Please enter cashiers Name:");
            cashier.setName(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please enter cashiers Address:");
            cashier.setAddress(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please enter Year of Birth(YYYY):");
            int YOB = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter Month of Birth(MM):");
            int MOB = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter Day of Birth(DD):");
            int dayOB = in.nextInt();
            dob.set(YOB,MOB,dayOB);
            cashier.setDOB(dob);
            cashId++;
            cashier.setCashierId(cashId);
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(cashier);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else if("Coff".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                          //finished
            System.out.println("Please Enter Name of Coffee:");
            c.setType(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please Enter Size of Coffee:");
            c.setSize(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please Enter Price of Coffee:");
            c.setPrice(in.nextDouble());
            coffId++;
            c.setCoffeeId(coffId);
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(c);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        }else{
            System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
        }
    }else if("R".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                                 //finished
        System.out.println("From what class would you like to Read? Transaction(Enter T), Cashier(enter Cash) or Coffee(Enter Coff):");
        choice = in.nextLine();
        if("T".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Transaction Id that you wish to view");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            b = em.find(Bill.class,IdChoice);
            System.out.println(b);
        }else if("Cash".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Cashier Id that you wish to view");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            cashier = em.find(Cashier.class, IdChoice);
    System.out.println(cashier);
        }else if("Coff".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Coffee Id that you wish to view");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            c = em.find(Coffee.class, IdChoice);
            System.out.println(c);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
        }
    }else if("U".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                                 //FINISHED
        System.out.println("From what class would you like to Update? Transaction(Enter T), Cashier(enter Cash) or Coffee(Enter Coff):");   
        choice = in.nextLine();
        if("T".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Transaction Id that you wish to Update");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            b = em.find(Bill.class, IdChoice);
            System.out.println("What would you like to update? Cashier name(C) or Bill(B)");
            choice = in.nextLine();
            if("C".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Enter Cashier Id you wish to use:");
                IdChoice = in.nextInt();
                cashier = em.find(Cashier.class, IdChoice);
                b.setTempname(cashier.getName());
            }else if("B".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Enter new Bill Amount:");
                double tempbill = in.nextDouble();
                b.setBill(b.calcBill(tempbill));
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");  
            }

        }else if("Cash".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Cashier Id that you wish to Update");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            cashier = em.find(Cashier.class, IdChoice);
            System.out.println("What would you like to update? Cashier name(N) Or Address(A)");                 // No date of birth option as you cant change when you are born
            choice = in.nextLine();
            if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Enter New Name:");
                cashier.setName(in.nextLine());
            }else if("A".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Enter New Address:");
                cashier.setAddress(in.nextLine());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
            }
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(cashier);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else if("Coff".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Coffee Id that you wish to Update");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            c = em.find(Coffee.class, IdChoice);
            System.out.println("Whar would you like to update? Coffee name(N),Size(S) or Price(P)");
            choice = in.nextLine();
            if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Please Enter New Name of Coffee:");
                c.setType(in.nextLine());
            }else if("S".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Please Enter New Size of Coffee:");
                c.setSize(in.nextLine());
            }else if("P".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
                System.out.println("Please Enter Price of Coffee:");
                c.setPrice(in.nextDouble());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
            }
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(c);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
        }
    }else if("D".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){                                                 //UNFINISHED
        System.out.println("From what class would you like to Delete? Transaction(Enter T), Cashier(enter Cash) or Coffee(Enter Coff):");
        choice = in.nextLine();
        if("T".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Transaction Id that you wish to Delete");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            b = em.find(Bill.class, IdChoice);
            em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(b);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else if("Cash".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Cashier Id that you wish to Delete");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            cashier = em.find(Cashier.class, IdChoice);
            em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(cashier);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else if("Coff".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
            System.out.println("Enter Coffee Id that you wish to Delete");
            IdChoice = in.nextInt();
            c = em.find(Coffee.class, IdChoice);
            em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error Incorrect value");
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue Y or N:");
    cont = in.nextLine();
}    








}
}
```

XML CLASS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SDEVRepeatCAPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>SDev3Repeat.Cashier</class>
    <class>SDev3Repeat.Coffee</class>
    <class>SDev3Repeat.Bill</class>
    <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hr"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="passhr"/>
  <!--      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.2.7:1521/global1"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>-->
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
```

And here is the full Output :

```
[EL Info]: 2017-08-22 17:45:37.248--ServerSession(1203142603)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Severe]: 2017-08-22 17:45:38.744--ServerSession(1203142603)--Exception 
[EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(SDev3Repeat.Bill --> [DatabaseTable(BILL)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

[EL Info]: connection: 2017-08-22 17:45:38.749--ServerSession(1203142603)--file:/C:/Users/Aran/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SDEV3RepeatCA/build/classes/_SDEVRepeatCAPU logout successful
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception 
[EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [SDEVRepeatCAPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2017-08-22 17:45:38.758--ServerSession(1203142603)--Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(SDev3Repeat.Bill --> [DatabaseTable(BILL)])

Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(SDev3Repeat.Bill --> [DatabaseTable(BILL)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:820)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:760)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at SDev3Repeat.TestCoffee.main(TestCoffee.java:15)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [SDEVRepeatCAPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(SDev3Repeat.Bill --> [DatabaseTable(BILL)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:238)
... 10 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(SDev3Repeat.Bill --> [DatabaseTable(BILL)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:696)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
... 8 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: I have a feeling its my relationship mapping thats the problem but i cant figure out what is wrong

Comment: Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException indicates an issue with the Bill constructor, but the stack you've shown is missing details.  I'd guess that your VAT should be marked as transient.

Comment: Ive made the Vat transient but unfortunately it didnt resolve my problem or change the output at all, any other ideas? also what do you mean by "the stack you've shown is missing details", ive provided all the information i wrote and recieved

Comment: Your constructor is causing an NPE - String tempname = cashier.getName(); will cause one.

Comment: Thank you so much, i was well and truly stumped, you saved me alot of hassle